# Сделать из String -> List<String>

Tags: java

Как конвертировать string такого формата ["junit", "tests", "cert"] в List с элементами junit, tests, cert

Comment: у вас на входе json? если так, то десериализация в помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такую конвертацию можно сделать разными способами, фактически это задача парсинга/сканирования строки.

- при помощи сканера и методов `Scanner::hasNext(String pattern)` / `Scanner::next(String pattern)`
- при помощи регулярных выражений и Stream API:

```java
// шаблон слова - всё что внутри кавычек
public static List<String> match(String str) {
    return Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"").matcher(str)
        .results()
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1))
        .toList();
}
```

- при помощи методов `String::replaceAll` + `String::split`

```java
// убрать ненужные символы '[]"' и разбить по разделителю ', '
public static List<String> split(String str) {
    return List.of(str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "").split(",\\s"));
}
```

- Аналогично с использованием `Pattern::splitAsStream`:

```java
public static List<String> split2(String str) {
    return Pattern.compile(",\\s")
        .splitAsStream(str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", ""))
        .toList();
}
```

- с использованием библиотек для парсинга JSON, как указал @tym32167 в комментарии.
  Например, можно применить де-факто стандартную библиотеку Jackson, а конкретнее метод `ObjectMapper::readValue` с указанием `TypeReference`, чтобы получить список строк:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public static List<String> parse(String str) {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        // сделает всю работу по чтению валидной JSON строки
        return om.readValue(str, new TypeReference<>() {});
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse list of strings from: " + str, ex);
    }
}
```

---

Тесты:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "[\"junit\", \"tests\", \"cert\"]";
    print(split(str));
    print(split2(str));
    print(match(str));
    print(parse(str));
}

static void print(List<String> lst) {
    System.out.println(lst.size() + ": " + lst);
}
```

```
3: [junit, tests, cert]
3: [junit, tests, cert]
3: [junit, tests, cert]
3: [junit, tests, cert]
```